# what this function does videooptflowlines() matlab?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

what is purpose of this function videooptflowlines(); also does the object hof contain information about previous frame to calculate optical flow?

```
hvfr = vision.VideoFileReader('viptraffic.avi', ...
                              'ImageColorSpace', 'Intensity', ...
                              'VideoOutputDataType', 'uint8');
hidtc = vision.ImageDataTypeConverter; 
hof = vision.OpticalFlow('ReferenceFrameDelay', 1);
hof.OutputValue = 'Horizontal and vertical components in complex form';
hsi = vision.ShapeInserter('Shape','Lines','BorderColor','Custom', 'CustomBorderColor',      255);
hvp = vision.VideoPlayer('Name', 'Motion Vector');
while ~isDone(hvfr)
    frame = step(hvfr);
    im = step(hidtc, frame); % convert the image to 'single' precision
    of = step(hof, im);      % compute optical flow for the video
    lines = videooptflowlines(of, 20); % generate coordinate points 
    if ~isempty(lines)
      out =  step(hsi, im, lines); % draw lines to indicate flow
      step(hvp, out);           % view in video player
    end
end
release(hvp);
release(hvfr);
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `videooptflowlines` is a helper function used by the demos ([`visiondemos`](http://www.mathworks.com/products/computer-vision/examples.html)) in the Computer Vision System toolbox. You can see the code for this function by typing `edit videooptflowlines` in the Matlab command window. A comment in the code states that, as its name indicates, the function is used in a help example for [`vision.OpticalFlow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.opticalflowclass.html#examples).

Essentially the function does the basic math to create vector lines that indicate optic flow direction. There are several parameters in the code that will probably depend on the resolution of the image used. If you're creating your own code that uses this function, you should probably create a copy of it and edit the new version to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your second question is "yes". A vision.OpticalFlow object does contain the information about the previous frame.